# Laravel: Textarea mailable deletes new pharagraphs

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.5

I have a contact form what if someone fills he will get a response email and I will get a "new message" email. I tested it with a five pharagraph Lorem Ipsum and it sends out in one pharagraph.
For example:
Input:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum
>   pharetra aliquam tellus condimentum rutrum. Maecenas id aliquam neque.
>   Phasellus a magna arcu. Suspendisse ut vehicula tortor. Donec quis
>   sodales arcu. Suspendisse viverra sapien dolor, eget aliquam augue
>   tempor ac. Nulla dictum justo ac scelerisque mattis. Proin viverra dui
>   nec quam feugiat placerat. Proin libero mi, sodales nec lorem id,
>   accumsan tristique felis. Donec consectetur, nibh vel tincidunt
>   aliquet, elit nisl congue ipsum, ut dictum eros nunc vitae justo.
>   Morbi euismod nibh et metus rhoncus dapibus. Phasellus hendrerit
>   iaculis nulla, a cursus nisl consectetur sit amet. Praesent auctor,
>   nisi non mattis mollis, felis odio euismod diam, vel auctor felis eros
>   sed nisl. Donec magna mauris, rutrum vitae cursus vel, volutpat id
>   enim. Fusce auctor, dolor et tristique accumsan, velit augue sagittis
>   lectus, sit amet mattis nisl velit gravida massa. Proin eget lorem
>   eleifend, consequat velit eget, volutpat ipsum.
>
> Proin nulla diam, malesuada id mi sed, sollicitudin pharetra massa. In
>   ac venenatis est, placerat viverra ante. Donec venenatis nisi elit,
>   sit amet semper libero hendrerit sit amet. Vivamus bibendum ipsum
>   arcu, accumsan condimentum massa molestie eget. Donec vel gravida
>   velit. Etiam dapibus tortor vel felis dapibus feugiat. Integer est
>   arcu, ullamcorper sed ornare ac, dignissim sed odio. Sed malesuada
>   pellentesque enim sed consequat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
>   faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Maecenas
>   pulvinar sodales iaculis. Quisque at libero ac ex viverra condimentum
>   id facilisis augue. Nam at orci lacus. Morbi sed aliquam elit, nec
>   condimentum neque. Sed pretium quam et tortor commodo gravida. Morbi
>   faucibus dapibus consequat.

Output:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum
>   pharetra aliquam tellus condimentum rutrum. Maecenas id aliquam neque.
>   Phasellus a magna arcu. Suspendisse ut vehicula tortor. Donec quis
>   sodales arcu. Suspendisse viverra sapien dolor, eget aliquam augue
>   tempor ac. Nulla dictum justo ac scelerisque mattis. Proin viverra dui
>   nec quam feugiat placerat. Proin libero mi, sodales nec lorem id,
>   accumsan tristique felis. Donec consectetur, nibh vel tincidunt
>   aliquet, elit nisl congue ipsum, ut dictum eros nunc vitae justo.
>   Morbi euismod nibh et metus rhoncus dapibus. Phasellus hendrerit
>   iaculis nulla, a cursus nisl consectetur sit amet. Praesent auctor,
>   nisi non mattis mollis, felis odio euismod diam, vel auctor felis eros
>   sed nisl. Donec magna mauris, rutrum vitae cursus vel, volutpat id
>   enim. Fusce auctor, dolor et tristique accumsan, velit augue sagittis
>   lectus, sit amet mattis nisl velit gravida massa. Proin eget lorem
>   eleifend, consequat velit eget, volutpat ipsum. Proin nulla diam,
>   malesuada id mi sed, sollicitudin pharetra massa. In ac venenatis est,
>   placerat viverra ante. Donec venenatis nisi elit, sit amet semper
>   libero hendrerit sit amet. Vivamus bibendum ipsum arcu, accumsan
>   condimentum massa molestie eget. Donec vel gravida velit. Etiam
>   dapibus tortor vel felis dapibus feugiat. Integer est arcu,
>   ullamcorper sed ornare ac, dignissim sed odio. Sed malesuada
>   pellentesque enim sed consequat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
>   faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Maecenas
>   pulvinar sodales iaculis. Quisque at libero ac ex viverra condimentum
>   id facilisis augue. Nam at orci lacus. Morbi sed aliquam elit, nec
>   condimentum neque. Sed pretium quam et tortor commodo gravida. Morbi
>   faucibus dapibus consequat.

In the developers tool: network it shows the right format.

My controller:

```
public function contactPost(Request $request){
    $name = $request -> name;
    $phone = $request -> phone;
    $email = $request -> email;
    $subject = $request -> subject;
    $message = $request -> message;

    $params = array(
        'name' => $name,
        'phone' => $phone,
        'email' => $email,
        'subject' => $subject,
        'message' => $message,
    );

    Mail::to($email)->send(new ContactMailResponse($params));
    Mail::to($adminMail)->send(new 
    ContactMail($params));

    return redirect("/#contact");
}
```

My mailable:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class ContactMailResponse extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($params)
    {
        $this->params = $params;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build(){

        $template = 'emails.contactemail';

        return $this->subject('Contact response')
                    ->view($template)
                    ->with(['params' => $this->params]);
    }
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Where's the email template code? looks like you're outputting `{{ content }}` instead of `{!! content !!}}` but cannot confirm without seeing the mail template.

Comment: I ouputted {{ $content }}, I tried with {!! $content !!} and now it works, thank you :)

Comment: added as an answer for you to tick for others to review if they're stuck in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're outputting `{{ content }}` instead of `{!! content !!}}`

Answer (score 2):

The line breaks in your text area value must be converted to `<br>` tags. You can do this using the `nl2br($plainText)` method in php.

```
'message' => nl2br($message),
```